# Design issue in Cucumber spring WebDriver quit in @After method

Tags: java, spring, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have a design issue when I am trying to build a framework using cucumber, selenium and cucumber-spring. My expected behavior is to quit WebdDriver instance for every scenario. But

Here is my page objects in `src\main\java`

```
@Component
public class BasePage {
WebDriver driver;
 public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

 }
 public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return this.driver;
  }

}
```

Here is another page object class which extends the Base class.

```
@Component
public class LoginPage extends BasePage
{
public LoginPage(WebDriver webDriver) {
    super(webDriver);
}

@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/app-root/s-login-pg/div/form/input[1]")
WebElement loginTextBox;

@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/app-root/s-login-pg/div/form/input[2]")
WebElement passwordTextBox;

@FindBy(xpath="/html/body/app-root/s-login-pg/div/form/button")
WebElement loginButton;

public void openApplication(String url){
    driver.get(url);
    waitForPageToLoad();
}

public void inputUsername(String username){
    loginTextBox.sendKeys(username);
}

public void inputPassword(String password){
    loginTextBox.sendKeys(password);
}

public void clickLoginButton(){
    loginButton.click();
 }
}
```

The webdriver is created with Factory Design pattern. Based on the browser mentioned in the properties file it will create the desired webdriver instance. And these Driver classes are not created with `@Component`

And spring configuration class under `src/test/java` as shown below.

```
@Configuration
@ContextConfiguration(classes={PropertiesContext.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.project")
public class CucumberContext {

@Autowired
private String browser;

  @Bean(name = "webdriver", destroyMethod = "quit")
  public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
    WebDriver webdriver = null;
    webdriver = DriverManagerFactory.getManager(browser).getDriver();
    return webdriver;
  }
}
```

This is the step definitions class under `src\test\java`

```
public class StepDefinitions extends ParentSteps {

@Autowired
private LoginPage loginPage;

@Autowired
private HomePage homePage;

@Before
public void init() {
    if (System.getProperty("environment") == null) {
        System.setProperty("environment", "DEV");
    }
}

@After
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
    if(loginPage.getDriver() != null) {
        loginPage.getDriver().quit;
    }
}
```

}

Here is my actual problem in the Step Definitions. For every Test Scenario If I call `driver.quit()` the remaining test scenarios will be failed with the below exception because the bean WebDriver killed in `@After`

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:125)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
```

The reason why I am getting this error is because the webdriver is closed which is an Injected bean. Is there any solution to create wedriver in @Before and kill webdriver in @After for each cucumber scenario? Is there any flaw in the design?

Comment: Are you running your scenarios in sequence or in parallel? what is the version of cucumber ?

Comment: I am running scenarios sequentially. I tried parallel as well but didn't worked. I am using the latest version `1.2.5`

Comment: Is there any specific reason to quit driver in the @After ? You will have to find equivalent solution in cucumber-spring . Something similar to '@ScenarioScoped' in cucumber-guice  https://static.javadoc.io/info.cukes/cucumber-guice/1.2.5/index.html

Comment: @vkrams latest version is 4.7.1

Comment: @RahulL I am using cucumber-jvm dependency. Need to check with cucumber.io. I want to quit driver because every time when I run a new scenario. I need to have a fresh browser so that the cookies or cached objects will not be present. Moreover I have identified few the driver process are not killed after executing of all the scenarios. This is a standard procedure in selenium to quit driver for every scenario.

Comment: I have to try spring `@DritiesContext`

Comment: `@DirtiesContext` works however the tests are very slow because its taking lot of time to load context for every test

Comment: @vkrams Tried above example by using @Scope("cucumber-glue") on all the component (Pages) + @Bean(name = "webdriver") . Working normally no slowness observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the @DirtiesContext used by OP as solution . Tried using @Scope(SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE)/@Scope("cucumber-glue") . Unique instance of Webdriver is created and destroyed in each scenario.

[Reference](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/spring)

Changing a Spring bean's scope to SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE will bound its lifecycle to the standard glue lifecycle.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import static io.cucumber.spring.CucumberTestContext.SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE;

@Component
@Scope(SCOPE_CUCUMBER_GLUE)
public class MyComponent {
}
```

Base Page:

```
@Component
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
public class BasePage {
WebDriver driver;
 public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

 }
 public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return this.driver;
  }

}
```

Base Page :

```
@Component
@Scope("cucumber-glue")
public class LoginPage extends BasePage
{
public LoginPage(WebDriver webDriver) {
    super(webDriver);
}

@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/app-root/s-login-pg/div/form/input[1]")
WebElement loginTextBox;

@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/app-root/s-login-pg/div/form/input[2]")
WebElement passwordTextBox;

@FindBy(xpath="/html/body/app-root/s-login-pg/div/form/button")
WebElement loginButton;

public void openApplication(String url){
    driver.get(url);
   // waitForPageToLoad();
}

public void inputUsername(String username){
    loginTextBox.sendKeys(username);
}

public void inputPassword(String password){
    loginTextBox.sendKeys(password);
}

public void clickLoginButton(){
    loginButton.click();
 }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
// Not define in example so commented @ContextConfiguration(classes= 
//{PropertiesContext.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.project")
public class CucumberContext {

@Autowired
private String browser;

  @Bean(name = "webdriver", destroyMethod = "quit")
  @Scope("cucumber-glue")
  public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
      WebDriver webdriver = null;
      // Removed the factory initialization code. Used simple ChromeDriver
      webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
      return webdriver;
  }
}
```

Steps:

```
public class StepDefinitions extends ParentSteps {

@Autowired
private LoginPage loginPage;

@Autowired
private HomePage homePage;

@Before
public void init() {
    if (System.getProperty("environment") == null) {
        System.setProperty("environment", "DEV");
    }
}

@After
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
   // Removed quit
   // if(loginPage.getDriver() != null) {
   //     loginPage.getDriver().quit;
  //   }
}
}
```

Note: All chromeriver background processes are killed.

Comment: Infact, I don't need to call the `driver.quit()` spring context itself tearing down the driver instance.

Comment: Yes I had observed that. So I had commented the code in @After method for quit call